# SQL Conditional Return HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, having, sql-date-functions

I have been unable to find the `WHERE` or `HAVING` condition that helps me return the following:

If a user has activity logged within the past month, I want to return records for the past six (6) months for those users. I have been using the following query so far...

```
SELECT
    USER, 
    CAST(ACTIVITY AS DATE), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ACTIONS), 
    SUM(RESULTS)
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    ACTIVITY >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    [conditions]
ORDER BY 
    [conditions]
```

I have attempted to use

```
HAVING 
    (COUNT(USER) * CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AS DECIMAL)) > 0
```

but I am getting records returns from inactive users who have only logged action within the past six (6) months, not the current or most recent month.

Comment: You can't do everything at once, so break your goal down into smaller pieces. And please remember that no one knows your business or your database so you need to use terminology that others understand. Step 1 - how do you find users that have activity logged within the past month? Define specifically what logic should be used. "Last month" can be interpreted in many ways and it might depend on the current date (or some other date) when the query is executed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for some guidance on how to improve your chances of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator with a subquery for the users with activity in the last month:

```
SELECT
    USER, 
    CAST(ACTIVITY AS DATE), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ACTIONS), 
    SUM(RESULTS)
FROM
    TABLE a
WHERE 
    ACTIVITY >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM   TABLE b
            WHERE  a.USER = b.USER AND
                   ACTIVITY >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY 
    USER
ORDER BY 
    [conditions]
```

Comment: Can this be accomplished without a trustworthy Table B? If a user DB is not reliable, I need to be able to base existing user viability based on user action.

Comment: @paaskanama `a` and `b` are different aliases **to the same table**. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I employed this EXISTS clause within my query and it seems to have filtered out the inactive users. Wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,

```
create table #date ( id int, logdate date)

insert #date values
  (1,'2018-08-03')  -- last month
, (1,'2018-05-03')  -- before 4 month
, (1,'2018-03-03')  -- before 6 month
, (1,'2018-02-03')  -- before 7 month
, (2,'2018-09-03')  -- logged on this month
, (2,'2018-05-03')  -- before 4 month
, (3,'2018-07-03')  -- before 2 month


select *, 'Who logged on before 6 months from last month'
from #date
WHERE DATEPART(m, logdate) <= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))                        -- logged date on last month
and DATEPART(m, logdate) >= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate()))                          -- logged date on before 6 months
and id in (                                                                                 -- 
 select id from #Date where DATEPART(m, logdate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))   -- 
)                                                                                           -- Ids who Logged in past month

/*      User 1, who logged on past month. So query gets his past 6 (3,4,5,6,7,8) month's logged date                    */
```

Revert me, if query will need update.